# Passing CSRF token in HTTP POST request (Django)

Tags: django, http, post, csrf

In an HTTP POST request sent to a server written in Django, one needs to include the csrfmiddlewaretoken value for the request to go through.

E.g.

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=4vn9gERLSuZxLR8hJnbT6Nth070goKkT&registration_id=foobar
```

My question is that is the csrfmiddlewaretoken value dynamic? If it is, it means the client has to somehow keep updating its knowledge of what the token is. In which case, how can my client have the correct token value at all times? Can I generate my own CSRF token?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `{% csrf_token %}` in your form template? Is it an ajax request?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/

Comment: My form template does have `{% csrf_token %}` in it. And I pass the token value every time I run a HTTP POST request via that template, otherwise I get "CSRF verification failed".

Comment: This is what's in my template: `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'registration_id' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="registration_id" value="{{ registration_id }}">
</form>`

Comment: So what's the problem? This is what you are supposed to do.

Comment: Daniel you're right. The problem is that when testing this, I pass this in POST: `csrfmiddlewaretoken=4vn9gERLSuZxLR8hJnbT6Nth070goKkT&registration_id=foobar` Now that csrfmiddlewaretoken value is hardcoded in the request. When it changes, the verification starts failing. How can my client-side remain abreast of whatever the "new" csrf value is?

Comment: Are you storing the csrfmiddlewaretoken value somewhere and trying to use it again?

Comment: No I'm not. Should I?